# sql ranking when 5 users have same points and ranks has to be skipped if users have same rank

Tags: mysql, sql

Rank users with same ranks if they have same points and then skip the rest of the ranks.

For eg: the table below shows that user 5 was first to respond 3 times hence his rank will be above all then user 4 then user1 and the rest? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.

```
    SELECT  name,
            (select count(*)
             from users u2
             where u2.points > u.points or
                   u2.points = u.points and u2.sno <= u.sno
            ) as rank
    FROM  `users` u GROUP BY  `name` ,  `sno`
ORDER BY CAST(points AS UNSIGNED) DESC;
```

USERS:

```
SNO points  first_to_respond   name
1    100   1                    a
2    100   0                    b
3    100   0                    c
4    100   2                    d
5    100   3                    e
```

Comment: if you want to know what the query does, just run it and see.

Comment: What is `sno` in the query?

Comment: I know what the query does I am using it I would like to know the best approach of the three above or any other way to rank when users have same points and you have to rank them.

Comment: updated the table now users_no

Comment: I'm assuming you are ranking based on points DESC so just order by something else too.  If you have a created field you can rank them based on who joined the most recently, or you can try that first to respond field there.  ORDER BY points DESC, first_to_respond

Comment: The best apprach depends on what you want for your application.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about defining the user's business logic for them.

Comment: I would like to know which would be better approach to rank?

Comment: This is like asking if a double-elimination tournament is better than single elimination. It is answered by doing the [requirements gathering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis) part of your development job.

Comment: Cool I think option 3 in the case above is best for now.Thanks for everything.

Comment: @Madbreaks AKA "primarily opinion-based" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a proper ranking as you are asking for:

```
SELECT  name,
        (select count(*) + 1
         from users u2
         where u2.points > u.points
        ) as rank
FROM  `users` u;
```

This counts the number that have more points, and then adds 1 to that value.

If you want to order by some other factor as well, then do something like:

```
SELECT  name,
        (select count(*) + 1
         from users u2
         where u2.points > u.points or
               u2.points = u.points and u2.first_to_respond < u.first_to_respond
        ) as rank
FROM  `users` u;
```

(I'm not sure if that second condition should be `<` or `>`.)

Comment: Basically it should be e > d> a> b >c

Comment: Hi I am stuck on the point: Shouldn't it be `from users AS u2`? Thanks.

Comment: @dollarvar . . . The `as` is optional for both table aliases and column aliases.  For column aliases `as` is good form because it prevents potential confusion.  For table aliases, it just tends to be query junk.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah cool, thanks, I am bad at MySql queries, but that's some knowledge I never would have seen elsewhere.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hello Sir Can you please explain `where u2.points > u.points`  whats difference between u2.points and u.points ? Confused there .

Comment: Thanks again Sir the code is working perfectly fine.Can you please clear the above confusion.

Comment: @jason . . . That is a correlated subquery.  You can think of it as going through each row in the outer query and running the inner query.  I would encourage you to play around with it to see what it produces under different circumstances (on a small dataset).  Correlated subqueries are quite useful, particularly in MySQL.

Comment: Awesome got it Sir will also try it out.Thanks again.